# SQL CASE expression not selecting largest value across 3 columns, neither is MAX

Tags: sql-server, max, case, multiple-columns

I am trying to find the largest value on row across 3 columns. I have tried several methods and they have all failed.

Original Data:

| max_adsl_predicted_down  | max_sfbb_predicted_down  | max_ufbb_predicted_down

| 10                       | 60                       | -1
                  |
 10                       | 80                       | 350
                 |
10                       | 1                        | -1

Desired Output:

| max_download  |

| 60            |

| 350           |

| 10            |

Data Sample and SQL used to generate it

```
Select TOP(379)
    max_adsl_predicted_down,
    max_sfbb_predicted_down,
    max_ufbb_predicted_down
FROM table
```

15  80  -1

15  80  -1

15  80  -1

15  80  -1

15  80  -1

15  80  -1

10  80  350

10  80  350

Using CASE expression:

```
SELECT TOP(379) 
    CASE WHEN max_ufbb_predicted_down > max_adsl_predicted_down AND max_ufbb_predicted_down > max_sfbb_predicted_down THEN max_ufbb_predicted_down
         WHEN max_sfbb_predicted_down > max_adsl_predicted_down AND max_sfbb_predicted_down > max_ufbb_predicted_down THEN max_sfbb_predicted_down
         WHEN max_adsl_predicted_down > max_sfbb_predicted_down AND max_adsl_predicted_down > max_ufbb_predicted_down THEN max_adsl_predicted_down
    END AS max_download
FROM table
```

80

80

80

80

80

80

80

80

Using MAX expression:

```
SELECT TOP(379)
      (SELECT MAX(speeds)
       FROM (VALUES (max_ufbb_predicted_down), (max_adsl_predicted_down), (max_sfbb_predicted_down)) as speeds(speeds) )AS max_download
FROM table
```

80

80

80

80

80

80

80

80

I do not understand why these methods have not returned the highest value on a row. Could you please suggest a solution or a reason why these methods didn't work?

Thank you,

Comment: On Stack Overflow, answers go in answers, questions are known to be dealt with when an answer is accepted. You don't edit answers into the question or change the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Tim's answer, what you can do is unpivot your data in a subquery and then use `MAX`:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(V.ColumnVal)
        FROM (VALUES(YT.max_adsl_predicted_down),
                    (YT.max_sfbb_predicted_down),
                    (YT.max_ufbb_predicted_down))V(ColumnVal)) AS max_download
FROM dbo.YourTable YT;
```

Comment: I am sorry this answer is also not working. I am at a loss why because it should solve my issue. It look like max_ufbb_predicted_down is simply ignored and only values from max_sfbb are returned.
Output is just
80
80
80
80
80
80
80
80
80
80
80
80

Comment: Both mine and Tim's solution work for me, @wojciech.pawlik, meaning that your implementation appears to be wrong: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cd6cdd66022395a8c52af3e8102587d0)

Comment: the output is rows of values from max_sfbb (where they are larger than max_adsl!) whilst larger values from max_ufbb are ignored.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue, @wojciech.pawlik , so my comment still stands. Sample data and expected results appear to be required here. I also **assume** you aren't foolishly doing something like storing numerical values as a `varchar`? The **`varchar`** `'100'` is **less than** `'80'` *not* greater than.

Comment: Thank you for narrowing it down. I will take your solutions and investigate my implementation more closely. I am quite baffled because I have literately copied and pasted your code (only changed YourTable). Can you think of any reasons why this solution might now work on my version of SSMS?

Comment: the version of SSMS has nothing to do with it. If the above SQL i provided in the fiddle produces different results on your instance, then something is wrong with your instance. That code works on SQL Server 2012-2019 and I'm sure it works on 2008 too (it won't on 2005, as `VALUES` was added in 2008).

Comment: I have indeed been a fool and didn't change column types after importing data from a flat file. I will fix that and get back to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support a scalar `GREATEST` function, as do many other databases.  In lieu of that, we can use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN max_adsl_predicted_down > max_sfbb_predicted_down AND
              max_adsl_predicted_down > max_ufbb_predicted_down
         THEN max_adsl_predicted_down
         WHEN max_sfbb_predicted_down > max_ufbb_predicted_down
         THEN max_sfbb_predicted_down
         ELSE max_ufbb_predicted_down END AS max_download
FROM yourTable;
```

The general form, easier to read, for three columns `col1`, `col2`, and `col3`, is:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN col1 > col2 AND col1 > col3 THEN col1
         WHEN col2 > col3 THEN col2
         ELSE col3 END AS greatest_col
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I am afraid this method isn't working and just returns 80s  instead of 350 on the last two rows. Do you have any idea why that may be?